# How to delete kernel locked files in c#

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

How to delete files e.g. "C:\Windows\system32\s2fb1c98721a1bb.idd.t_r" which is currently used by third party kernel-driver? One way is to delete the file before the kernel load. But how we can achieve that with C#?

Edit: Tried `MoveFileEx` but didn't work

Comment: You can't. C# isn't magic, and userland code is always subordinate to the kernel.

Comment: ...though if it's a well-designed driver (those are rarer than unicorn's teeth, honestly) then you might be able to safely unload it while Windows is running, which _should_ cause Windows to release the file allowing you to delete it through the normal Win32 userland filesystem API. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/385796/how-to-unload-a-windows-driver

Comment: But there has to be an approach whether with c# or batch command etc. Can't we delete those files before loading of 3rd party drivers?

Comment: Who says there "has" to be an approach?

Comment: Sorry I've a program named "RxSLTR64.exe" which is able to delete that file at startup. It's not written in c# BUT it works. I'm just trying to employ the whole thing in c#